# Checking if a quotient of a polynomial ring is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

> Show that $\mathbb{F}_2[X]/(x^3+x+1)$ is a field, while $\mathbb{F}_3[X]/(x^3+x+1)$ is not.

If I'm right I just need to show that $x^3+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2$ and reducible in $\mathbb{F}_3$, right?

preliminary thoughts: a polynomial $f(x)$ has a linear factor $x - a \Leftrightarrow f(a) = 0$.

For $\mathbb{F}_2$ applies: $f(0) = f(1) = 1 \neq 0 \Rightarrow f(x)$ irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2 \Rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2[X]/(x^3+x+1)$ is a field.

For $\mathbb{F}_3$ applies: $f(1) = 0 \Rightarrow$ f(x) has linear factor $(x-1)$ and therefore is reducible $\Rightarrow \mathbb{F}_3[X]/(x^3+x+1)$ is not a field.

Can you please tell me if this is correct?

Comment: Certainly it is correct..Where your doubt?

Comment: For the second  case the quotient is an additive  group also.

Comment: This is correct, but you need to be careful. A polynomial can have no linear factors, but still be irreducible. The point here is that since the polynomials are cubic, if they are reducible, then they must have a linear factor.

Comment: @Mathmo123 thank you for your hint! Can you provide a simple example of such an irreducible polynomial with a degree $> 3$?

Comment: Sorry irreducible should have said reducible. As an example, $x^4+x^2+1 \equiv (x^2+x+1)^2 \pmod2$, but has no linear factors mod 2. So checking that there are no linear factors is not sufficient in general. It works in the cubic case, since however you split a degree 3 polynomial, you get a linear factor

Comment: @Mathmo123 ah ok, that makes sense to me, thank you!